# @Query doesn't work in Spring Boot (JPA ) + Azure Cosmos db

Tags: azure, spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb

I'm developing some IoT application.
Data is in Azure Cosmos DB.
example)

```
{
        "id": "3ebd07c0-0740-466f-acb4-1e04a58cdf1a",
        "serviceId": 1,
        "deviceId": 1,
        "contents": "{\"temperature\":34.797642257199705,\"humidity\":79.18982439419167,\"illuminance\":100}",
        "date": 1552376519931
    }
```

So. I want to use custom query like this

```
public interface DeviceTelemetryRepository extends DocumentDbRepository<DeviceTelemetry, String> {

    @Query("SELECT a.deviceId FROM device_telemetry a where a.deviceId=:deviceId and a.date >=:from and a.date <=:to")
    List<DeviceTelemetry> findTelemetryByDeviceId(@Param("deviceId") int deviceId,
                                     @Param("from") long from,
                                     @Param("to") long to    );
}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class DeviceTelemetry {
    private String id;
    private int serviceId;
    private int deviceId;
    private String contents;
    private long date;
}
```

But it doesn't work.
I already tested it's query and data on Azure portal. It was ok.

I think that "DeviceTelemetryRepository extends DocumentDbRepository" cannot recognize @Query.

Do you have any suggestion about Spring Boot JPA + Azure Cosmos DB ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's spring-data-cosmosdb library doesn't support the @Query annotation.

Comment: Here's a reference to that fact: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/how-to-guides-spring-data-cosmosdb#custom-query-execution ...although it seems others have added JPA dependencies to get @Query support...and it somehow works. I wouldn't recommend it though. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55145163/1098564 . Also, as of March 2020, they were estimating it would be done in May 2020: https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/issues/389#issuecomment-597167571

Answer (score 2):

I know it is older post, if you are still facing any issue ,
you can try this, it worked for me

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM c where c.cityCode=@cityCode and c.marketCode=@marketCode")
    Flux<?> findAllByCityCodeAndMarketCode(@Param("cityCode") String cityCode, @Param("marketCode") String marketCode);
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-parameterized-queries

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is still facing this, `@Query` support has been incorporated in spring-data-cosmosdb 3.x

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-spring-data-cosmos

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM device_telemetry a where a.deviceId=:deviceId and a.date >=:from and a.date <=:to")
List<DeviceTelemetry> findTelemetryByDeviceId(@Param("deviceId") int deviceId,
                                 @Param("from") Date from,
                                 @Param("to") Date to    );
```

Comment: I think that it's not about the data type problem. Because I'm using long type on other components.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of method. It works !

```
List<DeviceTelemetry> findDeviceTelemetryByDeviceIdAndDateBetween(@Param("deviceId") int deviceId,
                                                               @Param("from") long from,
                                                               @Param("to") long to    );
```

but It doesn't still recognize @Query
Please, let me know how to work with Query annotation.