# Is there a @Query for azure cosmosDB? (DocumentDb)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Like we use @Query for sql driver, or jpa, what is the alternative annotation for azure cosmosDB(DocumentDb) to use in the java class?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqINn.png)

Comment: I have attached the sample @Query for jpa.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain actual code, not an image of code.

Answer (score 1):

As i searched for [spring-data-cosmosdb source code](https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-cosmosdb/tree/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/spring/data/cosmosdb/core/mapping), it does not support `@Query` annotation. Please refer to below cases:

1.[Is there any way to write custom or native queries in Java JPA (DocumentDbRepository) while firing a query to azure-cosmosdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57907452/is-there-any-way-to-write-custom-or-native-queries-in-java-jpa-documentdbreposi)

2.[@Query doesn't work in Spring Boot (JPA ) + Azure Cosmos db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134836/query-doesnt-work-in-spring-boot-jpa-azure-cosmos-db)

Besides,you could ask the support of this feature in this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) or contact with azure cosmos db team directly there.

Comment: thanks. I did not use same clause to achieve the functionality, but did a bit longer coding. For now, I am able to achieve the goal. If I need to change it, I will follow the link that you have sent here. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @YubrajTamang You're welcome,if you think the answer is beneficial to you,would you please accept it an answer(hook beside answer),thanks.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you send some screenshot if possible?

Comment: @YubrajTamang Hi,just mark the hook beside my answer,please see this link:meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/… Thank you!

Comment: I did. So, is there any way of using query within the java class? because, i don't want to fetch millions of data doing (findAll()) method.

Answer (score 0):

The updated version

> ```
> <dependency>
> <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
> <artifactId>azure-spring-data-cosmos-core</artifactId>
> <version>3.0.0-beta.1</version> 
> </dependency>
> ```

which was released in August 2020 does support @Query.
You can find the documentation over [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos).